# Fixing the Aztec decoder in Zxing (Obj-C) to return raw ByteArray

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, zxing

I'm working on an iOS app that's supposed to decode a certain type of Aztec barcode ([example](http://www.regensblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/munich_bolzano.pdf), PDF). I need the scanner to return the data on a low level, since it's zlib compressed and I need to decompress it afterwards. The built-in barcode scanner using `AVCapture` works fine for regular string data but [fails in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438301/override-the-stringvalue-property-of-avmetadatamachinereadablecodeobject-or-crea).

I have turned to `Zxing`, or rather its `Objective C` port [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC), in the hope of being able to access the decoded barcode data before it gets turned into a string. I was half successful. The `ZXResult` returned does contain a `ZXByteArray` called `rawBytes`, but **only** for QR codes (for Aztec codes it's `nil`)! I looked inside [ZXAztecDecoder.m](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC/blob/master/ZXingObjC/aztec/decoder/ZXAztecDecoder.m#L69-L85) and sure enough, the byte array is never populated, not even in the original `Zxing` code in `Java`.
Someone tried to fix it for the original library ([Pull Request](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/pull/389), Line 80) by doing

```
byte[] rawBytes = convertBoolArrayToByteArray(correctedBits);
```

I'd like to add the same functionality for `ZXingObjC`, but I'm stuck trying to convert the`ZXBoolArray` to a `ZXByteArray`. Here is the decode function as I envision it:

```
- (ZXDecoderResult *)decode:(ZXAztecDetectorResult *)detectorResult error:(NSError **)error {
    self.ddata = detectorResult;
    ZXBitMatrix *matrix = [detectorResult bits];
    ZXBoolArray *rawbits = [self extractBits:matrix];
    if (!rawbits) {
        if (error) *error = ZXFormatErrorInstance();
        return nil;
    }

    ZXBoolArray *correctedBits = [self correctBits:rawbits error:error];
    if (!correctedBits) {
        return nil;
    }

    ZXByteArray *rawBytes = /* somehow turn correctedBits into ZXByteArray */;

    NSString *result = [[self class] encodedData:correctedBits];
    return [[ZXDecoderResult alloc] initWithRawBytes:rawBytes text:result byteSegments:nil ecLevel:nil];
}
```

If somebody knows how to do this or has an idea how to go about it, I'd appreciate it. If it works out, I'd like to contribute the code to `ZXingObjC`, so this won't bug people in the future. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually a solution to the problem, but my persistent nagging helped fix [this overdue issue](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/pull/583) in the original ZXing Github repo. If that change makes it upstream into `ZXingObjC` at some point, I can close this question for good.

If anybody wants to help translate these `Java` lines ([source](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/pull/591/files)) to `Objective-C`, I'd surely appreciate it.

```
/**
  * Reads a code of length 8 in an array of bits, padding with zeros
  */
private static byte readByte(boolean[] rawbits, int startIndex) {
    int n = rawbits.length - startIndex;
    if (n >= 8) {
        return (byte) readCode(rawbits, startIndex, 8);
    }
    return (byte) (readCode(rawbits, startIndex, n) << (8 - n));
}

/**
  * Packs a bit array into bytes, most significant bit first
  */
static byte[] convertBoolArrayToByteArray(boolean[] boolArr) {
    byte[] byteArr = new byte[(boolArr.length + 7) / 8];
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArr.length; i++) {
        byteArr[i] = readByte(boolArr, 8 * i);
    }
    return byteArr;
}
```